# Tell/verify properties of boot loader

Tags: boot-loader, secure-boot

Given that we have a USB stick with GRUB boot loader, how to tell (from Linux command line)

- whether it is UEFI?
- whether it is secure boot and verify it?

As for research, there are guides for creating such a loader, however, I could not find how to tell about existing loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a partition on the USB stick, whose root directory contains a subdirectory named `EFI` or `efi` (UEFI is supposed to be case-insensitive with filenames), it's probably intended to be UEFI-bootable. Ideally, that partition should have a FAT32 filesystem, but some UEFI firmwares will support other filesystem types like ISO9660, NTFS or HFS+ too.

On a removable media, the actual UEFI bootloader for 64-bit x86 hardware will be a file in path `<partition root>/efi/boot/bootx64.efi`. This is actually the standard pathname for the removable media bootloader. On permanent OS installations, the bootloader pathname will instead be `<partition root>/efi/<OS vendor or Linux distribution name>/<something>.efi`. The OS installer will store this pathname into an UEFI NVRAM boot variable, which is similar to BIOS settings, but actually has a standardized interface that allows it to be queried and manipulated by the OS while it is running.

In Linux, `efibootmgr -v` command is one way to display the UEFI NVRAM boot variables; the `bootctl` command of the `systemd-boot` bootloader will also show some of the boot variable information.

A removable media might be BIOS-bootable and UEFI-bootable at the same time. In that case, it will include two bootloaders: one BIOS-compatible bootloader (perhaps SYSLINUX) embedded in the MBR, and a UEFI-compatible bootloader as described above.

If you use the `file` command to identify the type of an `.efi` file, it will say something like this:

```
# file bootx64.efi 
bootx64.efi: PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
```

In other words, UEFI bootloader uses the same executable file format as Microsoft Windows does. PE32+ is the 64-bit executable format; if you see a 32-bit UEFI implementation, it might use the 32-bit PE32 format (without the `+` sign).

Note: UEFI supports multiple hardware architectures. Some ARM systems might also use UEFI.

Secure Boot is a subset of UEFI. A non-UEFI bootloader cannot be Secure Boot compliant. To see if a `.efi` file has a Secure Boot signature embedded to it, you can use `pesign -S -i filename.efi`.

```
# pesign -S -i bootx64.efi 
---------------------------------------------
certificate address is 0x7fb0f0f8dd80
Content was not encrypted.
Content is detached; signature cannot be verified.
The signer's common name is Microsoft Windows UEFI Driver Publisher
No signer email address.
No signing time included.
There were certs or crls included.
---------------------------------------------
```

If there is no Secure Boot signature present, the output will be like this instead:

```
# pesign -S -i ipxe.efi 
No signatures found.
```

Since Microsoft's signing certificate is included in the Secure Boot firmwares of most UEFI PCs on the market, and Microsoft also provides an UEFI bootloader signing service for others, the most common signature you will find on Secure Boot-compatible Linux bootloaders is probably going to be Microsoft's.

If a removable media with GRUB is Secure Boot-compatible, the actual `<partition root>/efi/boot/bootx64.efi` file is most likely the *shim pre-loader*. On permanent Linux installations on Secure Boot systems, you'll find the shim pre-loader as `shimx64.efi` instead. It can add Secure Boot support for the distribution maintainer's own signing certificate, and optionally for the system owner's own certificate (known as MOK = Machine Owner's Key) too. This is an unfortunate necessity because not all UEFI firmware implementations will allow customization of the Secure Boot keys included in the firmware in any easy way.

After adding its certificate(s), the shim pre-loader will load the actual bootloader, named `grubx64.efi` in the same directory. (Technically it doesn't actually have to be GRUB; that's just the default filename programmed into the shim pre-loader.) That file must also be signed, but it is likely signed with the distribution maintainer's own certificate, instead of Microsoft's.

The purpose of this is to allow the distribution maintainer to easily package and publish updated versions of GRUB as required, as they can now be signed with the distribution maintainer's own key. If the shim pre-loader needs to be updated, the distribution maintainer will need to contact Microsoft to have the updated shim signed again.